# How to remove chromium log in Android Studio (LogCat)

Tags: android, cordova

When I open the webview Cordova (app in release mode) The logcat show these logs I/chromium: [INFO: CONSOLE(1)] source http://.....

How to remove these logs into my application "I/chromium: [INFO: CONSOLE(1)], in Android Studio (LogCat)? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's possible.
[Using Console APIs in WebView](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/debugging#WebView)

Just override WebViewClient for your WebView like this:

```
val myWebView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.webview)
myWebView.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {

override fun onConsoleMessage(consoleMessage: ConsoleMessage?): Boolean {
    consoleMessage?.apply {
        Log.d("MyApplication", "${message()} -- From line ${lineNumber()} of ${sourceId()}")
    }
    return true
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed it directly on SystemWebChromeClient.java by commenting the line Log.d(….) and it's working perfectly

Comment: The important part is to return "true" instead of "super.onConsoleMessage(consoleMessage)" like the default override.

Answer (score 0):

@Volodymyr ans work for me. Just override onConsoleMessage on WebChromeClient ([reference](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/debugging#WebView)):

```
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage consoleMessage) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onConsoleMessage: "+ consoleMessage.message());
            return true;
        }
    });
```